# damaged kindle- change lines per page?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, mobi

this is a long shot but I thought I would try:

My older Kindle (6", b&w, no backlight) has sustained some damage to the bottom (1/3" or less) of the screen - not visibly cracked just unresponsive.  Now it is still almost usable, however the bottom line or half line of every page (or every other page) gets cut off and I can't read it.  Is there any way, through either editing the MOBI file, or perhaps the Kindle settings ("jailbreaking??"), that I can force a page break or make it display one line less on every page?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the value of the HORIZONTAL_MARGIN parameter in the reader.pref configuration file (in the system directory). You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7777106/21348) or [here](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_HowTo:_Change_Margin).

Comment: Great,  thank you. I found that by rotating the screen combined and turning down the "words per line"  as explained in your link I am able to make it quite usable again

Answer (score 0):

Ebooks, by design, are typically formatted as "reflowable" text. This gives readers the freedom to choose font size and other page settings.

Ebooks can also be "Fixed Layout". Publishers/ authors generally choose to use fixed when more control over the content contained within the file is needed, like Ebooks with multiple images, charts or tables.

In your case, I assume most of the content you are displaying on your b&w Kindle is plain text with an occasional image. If you want TOTAL control of each page (e.g, reflowing the last couple lines of text on every page to the top of the next page) I believe you would need to reformat each file....using a program like Calibre.

Another possible solution may be tricking or altering the settings in your reader (if possible) to think its a 5" display instead of 6".

Good luck.